# Can't get past the pulsating boot screen after complete battery drain

Tags: battery, samsung-nexus-s, reboot

My phone ran out of charge this morning after I made a couple of phone calls in bed. I was too lazy to get out of bed to plug it in. When I plugged it in later, and pushed the power button, the phone is continously looping the pulsating X loading animation. The only way to switch it off at this point is to replace the battery.

I [read](http://www.knowyourcell.com/google/google-nexus-s/nexus-s-guides/693669/how_to_hard_reset_the_google_nexus_s.html) about the hard reset and tried that too. It didn't help.

Update:
I also tried setting the battery aside for over 15 mins before replacing and trying it again.

I was able to get into recovery by holding down the POWER + VOL UP buttons. Tried the "wipe cache partition" option thinking that the phone refused to start due to some stale cache. It didn't help either.

What else can I do to revive the phone? I would like not to lose data, if I can. But it's more important to get the phone working.

Comment: Try using adb from the Android SDK tools.  I'd try going into fastboot and restarting from there ... if all else faios you can also re-flash your ROM from there.

Comment: Oh, and did you make sure you charged the battery a bit?  Voltage can be unstable below ~20% charge.

Comment: Charged the battery completely before attempting to turn it on again after a few failed attempts. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I had was to do a factory reset and reinstall all the apps using appbrain.

Comment: That's a bummer. I hope for you that this was a one-time thing. (Please remember to "accept" this answer.)